# Software Updater not showing what it wants to update

Tags: update-manager

After a regular update it wanted to update again. 4.5mb but its completely blank about what is going to be updated.[image]

dmesg said:

```
type=1400 audit(1616008197.506:135): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/core/10859/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=26782 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
```

Comment: I saw this too. Switched to command line and it was helpful, but I can't remember the details.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It's just a glitch but Ubuntu is really not supposed to be downloading stuff you don't know

Comment: As @OrganicMarble says, when anything like this goes wrong in a GUI front end, the best thing is to switch to the CLI and run apt/apt-get/dpkg directly. Then, you get to see all the detailed things it wants to do or is upset about.